# Push notifications IOS react native NSDictionary error

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I used this library to create push notifications in my react native app.

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification .

I tried to send a local notification, the code is :

```
localNotif() {
    this.lastId++;
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      /* Android Only Properties */
      id: ''+this.lastId, // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
      ticker: "My Notification Ticker", // (optional)
      autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
      largeIcon: "ic_launcher", // (optional) default: "ic_launcher"
      smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default: "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
      bigText: "My big text that will be shown when notification is expanded", // (optional) default: "message" prop
      subText: "This is a subText", // (optional) default: none
      color: "red", // (optional) default: system default
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
      vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
      tag: 'some_tag', // (optional) add tag to message
      group: "group", // (optional) add group to message
      ongoing: false, // (optional) set whether this is an "ongoing" notification

      /* iOS only properties */
      alertAction: 'view', // (optional) default: view
      category: null, // (optional) default: null
      userInfo: null, // (optional) default: null (object containing additional notification data)

      /* iOS and Android properties */
      title: "Local Notification", // (optional)
      message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
      playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
      soundName: 'default', // (optional) Sound to play when the notification is shown. Value of 'default' plays the default sound. It can be set to a custom sound such as 'android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound'. It will look for the 'my_sound' audio file in 'res/raw' directory and play it. default: 'default' (default sound is played)
      number: '10', // (optional) Valid 32 bit integer specified as string. default: none (Cannot be zero)
      actions: '["Yes", "No"]',  // (Android only) See the doc for notification actions to know more
    });
  }
```

I got this error :

JSON value of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSDisctionary

Comment: Can you put an error screen?

Comment: this is the only error message i got in my Iphone

Comment: Is this a crash (with a red screen) or only a warning message?

Comment: a red screen ( i think the userInfo property can't be empty ) but i don't know what type it should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the following changes in your JSON :

```
 category: null, // either pass a string here OR Remove this.
 userInfo: null, // either pass a JSON here OR Remove this.
 number: '10' // make this a number as 10
```

This may be a possible errors. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara : Remove category and userInfo and Pass number : 10. Please read comment in front of the line in my code snippet

Comment: I removed category and userInfo and i set number to 10, i don't get error by i got anything i don't receive any push